# Block access to a file using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xss

I have a .htaccess inside a folder with:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
Satisfy Any
```

I try to limit access to a file that contains a hashed key, only to the same domain, to avoid Cross-site request forgery.
I want only example.com to be able to read that file and not foreign_example.com, but 
when i read the file with a GET request a status of 403 forbidden is showed.

Edit1: I am using LiteSpeed Web Server which support htaccess module from Apache.

Comment: The code from my questions is the right answer from that question, but not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the "allow orign" method of Htaccess.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Hope it works.
Best regards.
Jonas

Comment: Also when you change the "example.com" to your actual domain? Have you removed your earlier code?